# How to disable a control inside a User Control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, markup

I thought this would be a simple thing to accomplish but am having some issue. My initial asp.net markup for the server control looks like this:

```
<ucTextArea:UserControlTextArea ID="taRemarks" runat="server" />
```

However, in the code behind, I have a conditional statement that checks for user rights in order to enable this text field or not, something like this:

```
if (CurrentUser.AccountTypeID == 4 || CurrentUser.AccountTypeID == 6)
    taRemarks.Attributes.Add("enabled", "");
else
    taRemarks.Attributes["disabled"] = "true";
```

Above are two ways I have tried to accomplish this, but haven't worked when rendered in the browser. How can I disable this server control?

Edit: The UserControlTextArea.ascx is defined below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserControlTextArea.ascx.cs"  Inherits="stuff....UserControlTextArea" %>

<script type="text/jscript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counterLabel = $('#<%=lblCounter.ClientID %>');
        var textArea = $('#<%=tbTextArea.ClientID %>');
        var maxNumber = parseInt('<%=txtMaxCharacters.Value%>');
        FieldCounter(textArea, counterLabel, maxNumber);

        $(textArea).keyup(function () {
            CheckFieldLength($(textArea), maxNumber);
            FieldCounter(textArea, $(counterLabel), maxNumber);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="OuterContainer" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbTextArea" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="fieldLengthCounter">
        characters left: 
        <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </span>
    <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="txtMaxCharacters" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use `taRemarks.Enabled = false;`?

Comment: You would think right? But no such property.

Comment: What all controls do you have in your `usercontrol`? Which control you wanna disable?

Comment: There's a number of controls in that uc. The one I want to disable is the one I mentioned above, "taRemarks".

Comment: Thats not an `ASP.NET Textbox` first of all, for me by naming convention its a `UserControl` and inside it there must be your textbox. If possible show the mark-up of `UserControlTextArea `

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry it's a UserControl with a textbox inside. This differentiation and understanding was what was preventing me from solving this issue.

Comment: Alright. Check my answer, just replace the textbox id with that of yours. It should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but definitely its a `UserControl` and not a ASP.Net Textbox. So you can disable the textbox inside your UC like this:-

**Approach 1 (Preferred):**

Add a public property in your UserControl code-behind:-

```
public bool DisableMyTextbox
{
   set { tbTextArea.Enabled = value; }
}
```

Then you can simply use this property to disable your textbox in Webform:-

`UserControlTextArea.DisableMyTextbox = false;` //or true to enable back.

**Approach 2:**

Find your textbox in UserControl class and then disable it:-

```
TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)SimpleUserControl1.FindControl("tbTextArea");
txt1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: How would I get the correct ID of the textbox? As it stands now, in my markup it's just the UserControl until the page is loaded and the ID is auto-generated.

Comment: This is my UserControl as stated above: <ucTextArea:UserControlTextArea ID="taRemarks" runat="server" />

Comment: Okay but you must have registered that right? Check for `Register` directive at the top or search it in Web.Config file, you will have the `src` or source of the usercontrol file, you can check that. Otherwise in worst case check its id from developer tool, its id must be appended with that of your UC Id.

Comment: I see now, okay I've added the code for the usercontrol file, the ID "tbTextArea" still isn't recognized.

Comment: Yup you need to find it, it won't come in visual studio intellisense, if you follow approach 2. Or if you follow approach 1 , just add that property in code behind of UserControlTextArea.ascx file i.e. `UserControlTextArea.ascx.cs` and then set in your webform.

Comment: I understand now! It all makes sense, thank you! I've learned quite a bit with this.